# Javascript - Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am relatively new at Javascript, and I have a page that calls a javascript function on `onkeyup`, but when called it throws an exception, `Uncaught ReferenceError: validate is not defined`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(id){
        alert(id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://example.com/restaurant/submit/verify",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                field: id,
                content: $('#' + id).val()
            }
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                if(data.status == "PASSED"){
                    $('#' + id).removeClass('has-error');
                    $('#' + id).addClass('has-success');
                } else if(data.status == "FAILED") {
                    $('#' + id).removeClass('has-success');
                    $('#' + id).addClass('has-error');
                    $('#' + id + ' div').append('<span class="help-inline">' + data.error + '</span>')
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, if you need more info, don't hesitate to ask. Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: where do u call `validate()` ?

Comment: I call validate from an input tag in a `onkeyup` attribut like so: `<input onkeyup="validate('street')" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="street" id="street" />
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a comma and a semicolon:

```
    function validate(id){
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.com/restaurant/submit/verify",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            field: id,
            content: $('#' + id).val()
        }, // Here
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            if(data.status == "PASSED"){
                $('#' + id).removeClass('has-error');
                $('#' + id).addClass('has-success');
            } else if(data.status == "FAILED") {
                $('#' + id).removeClass('has-success');
                $('#' + id).addClass('has-error');
                $('#' + id + ' div').append('<span class="help-inline">' + data.error + '</span>'); // and here
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot, sorry I was misunderstanding because it told me that the function was undefined

Comment: No problem. If this post solved your issue, please mark it as a correct answer